# Prove for $\epsilon >0$ exists a finite interval $[a,b]$ such that $|\int{f(x)}dx-\int_{a}^b f(x)dx|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ Lebesgue integrable. Prove that for $\epsilon >0$ there exists a finite interval $[a,b]$ such that

$$\left|\int{f(x)}dx-\int_{a}^b f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon.$$

**My attempt:** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any measurable set $D \subset [a,b]$ with measure $\mu(D) < \delta$ we have

$$\left|\int_{a}^b f(x)dx\right|<\epsilon/2.$$

This is where I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to $\{\chi_{[-n,n]} f\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: I don’t understand.... The first integral is indefinite, so the difference will be a constant of integration plus some other value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily show via dominated convergence that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x)dx=\int f(x)dx.
$$
By definition, for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, this means that for all $N$ large enough,
$$
\bigg\vert \int f(x)dx-\int_{-N}^N f(x)dx\bigg\vert<\epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$ and $$A_1\subset A_2\subset\dots,$$ then $$\int_A f\,\text{d}\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_n} f\,\text{d}\mu.$$ This is the fundamental property of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: I wouldn't call this **the** fundamental property of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Well, this is obviously a matter of opinion, but this wording (with the definite article) suggests that this property somehow captures the essence and meaning of the Lebesgue integral which I wouldn't quite agree with.

Comment: So, this is the ''language problem''. If you are thinking in this way, I agree, this is not the essence of the Lebesgue integral. However, to make this discussion clear for the reader, I leave the form I used.